# Transfer data from Excel to table

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017, excel

How can I transfer information from an Excel file to a table in a SQL server database through SSMS?

Excel file Consists of five columns and a thousand rows.

[image]

I followed the steps as explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seS8Yd_6nzs),at second 00:52 I can not continue because of the following error message :

> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0' provider is not registered on the local
>   machine. (System.Data)

I tried to export the excel file to different versions of Microsoft(2003, 2007, 2010) but the problem was not solved.

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: You can use dbatool's  `Import-DbaCsvToSql` https://dbatools.io/functions/import-dbacsvtosql/  module or use https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

Comment: Have you tried Import/export wizard? https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

You must install the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016, as Justin Onstot already wrote (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920), and ALSO you MUST run the correct version of Import/Export application (32 or 64 bit) to be successful. You have a 64-bit SQL Server, so you must install the 64-bit Access Database Engine and perform the following steps:

- Go to Start Menu -> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 ->  SQL Server 2017 Import and Export Data (64-bit)
- Open the application and try to import data using the "Excel 2016" option, it should work fine.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to install the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable available at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920. You'll need to choose either the 32-bit or 64-bit executable depending on your environment. This was the fix for me when I got this error using the SSIS import/export wizard with 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Save the excel as a CSV and [import it as a flat file](https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1179/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-a-database-using-sql-server-management-studio.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Go [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920), download `Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable` and install
2. Close SQL Server Management Studio
3. Go to Start Menu -> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 ->  SQL Server 2017 Import and Export Data (64-bit)
4. Open the application and try to import data using the "Excel 2016" option, it should work fine.

Hope this helps.